# How do I use `SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings` in swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2

I am working on certificate verification code for a `NSURLSession` in Swift. I would like to automatically adjust the trust settings for our own certificate which is used by a server.

The relevant code section is shown below:

```
SecCertificateAddToKeychain(firstCertificate, nil)
let sslTrust: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [kSecTrustSettingsPolicy: SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, nil)]
let result = SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings(firstCertificate, .User, sslTrust)
if (result == errSecSuccess) {
    // success
} else {
    print("Could not set trust settings \(result)")
}
```

I always get the result `-50`, which is `errSecParam` stating "One or more parameters passed to the function were not valid.".

If I replace the dictionary with an empty array `[]`, the function returns success, so the problem is this last parameter.

**How do I correctly use this function in swift?**

Comment: I've found a project that use this class. Perhaps this link help you https://github.com/Bouke/Swift-Security/blob/9e909663076674d23dd765c90b9dc52b51ec552e/Swift-Security/TrustSettings.swift

Comment: @David I had already a look on this project, but it seems to be written for swift 1 and uses own enumerations instead of the provided symbols from the library.